# How to use Pinia to store initial state from server api in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

I want to store datas in Pinia at first when site is loaded, so I can get data from Pinia while going through pages without keeping calling api.

But when I want to use the datas with array methods like filter,
I got an error says "500 Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')".

Can the problem been solved?
If there are better ways to implement the feature, please tell me.

Here are my codes:

pages/restaurants/[slug].vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul class="c-cardList">
      <li class="c-card" v-for="item in filteredRestaurants" :key="item.id">
        <div class="c-card_name">{{ item.data[0].data }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  const { data: restaurants } = useRestaurants();

  const category = "cafe";

  const filteredRestaurants = ref(
    restaurants.value.filter(element => {
      return element.data[1].data[0] == category;
    })
  );
</script>
```

composables/useRestaurants.ts

```
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { useRestaurantsStore } from '@/store/restaurants';


export default function () {

  const restaurantsStore = useRestaurantsStore();
  restaurantsStore.callData();
  const { data } = storeToRefs(restaurantsStore);
  
  return {
    data
  }

}
```

store/restaurants.ts

```
export const useRestaurantsStore = defineStore(
  "restaurants",
  {
    state: () => ({
      data: null,
    }),
    actions: {
      async callData() {
        const { data } = await useFetch('/api/restaurants');
        this.data = data.value.items;
      },
    },
  }
 );
```

Comment: Do you have the array populated aka does it work without the `.filter` on it?

Comment: It worked without any Array methods like I can check data by using `console.log(restaurants.value)`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get data by adding await before `useRestaurants()` !

```
const { data: restaurants } = await useRestaurants();
```

Comment: Yep, that's because the array is empty initially so you cannot filter on it. Hence why a condition or an await are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not awaiting the results of async `callData` when initializing the store, so the program continues to initializing `filteredRestaurants` and fails, because `restaurants` are not populated yet.

You can for example change `filteredRestaurants` from `ref` to `computed`, so it will track the changes and re-calculate when data is fetched, and add optional chaining to avoid initial failure:

```js
const filteredRestaurants = computed(() => restaurants.value?.filter(element => element.data[1].data[0] === category));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I managed to get data by adding `await` before `useRestaurants()`. I will try your solution too.

Comment: I was considering this approach as well, I just wasn't sure about top level await in Nuxt. In vanilla Vue it needs to be used with `<suspense>` element in template (https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await), I guess Nuxt is utilizing this out of the box, but I am lacking insight to confirm that.